# Is there any expiration date strategy on PouchDB like Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, pouchdb

I work with PouchDb and looking for something like Expiration date in Redis who when creating a row (pushing a doc) put a date time or tell the database to delete this row after 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

`PouchDb` doesn't have TTL for entries like `Redis`. You can, however, use compaction if you wish to delete any entry. But it would still hold the rev id to the doc for conflict resolution, only metadata shall be removed.

If you want to delete entries which are 30 mins old:

- Create an index of timestamp provided.
- periodically fetch entries 30 mins older, filters are supported.[here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_index)
- delete all entries matching the queried index.